# How do you get around the ABA problem when using mwaitx?

Tags: assembly, locking, x86-64

AMD's `mwaitx` instruction allows you to wait for an address to change, and it has a limited duration. There's no way to tell if it woke up because the value changed or because of an interrupt.

You can always inspect the address to see if it's changed, but this leads to the ABA problem where it could've changed, then changed back.

This can lead to an issue where you might want to send an update request for a data block if its associated lock was accessed, but if the lock is acquired, used, then released, the data structure changed but the value of the lock doesn't APPEAR to have changed, and the thread using `mwaitx` isn't aware that the lock was accessed.

Is there any workaround for this or am I stuck?

Comment: Not sure what your use case is, but normally either 1) it does not change back because your code would be the one doing that or 2) if somebody else did change it back then that is fine, go back to waiting

Comment: @harold I've added context

Comment: The standard solution for the ABA problem is to attach a change counter to the value. That way if the value changes back, the change counter will still be different.

Comment: @RaymondChen that defeats the purpose of using mwaitx, no?

Comment: No.  If you want to use it to monitor a lock, you could have the low bit mean taken vs. free, and the higher bits be a counter that makes it unique.  Taking the lock would be `lock bts dword [mem], 0` to test-and-set the low bit.  Releasing the lock would be `add dword [mem], 1` (without a `lock` prefix since no other threads will be changing the value; at most they'll set the low bit which was already set.  Or just load the lock value, inc it, and do a normal `mov` release-store.  But a memory-destination `add` is equivalent.)

Comment: @PeterCordes In my code example, I believe I've made a mistake: I think you have to `monitor` before you try to get the spin lock as otherwise there's possibly a brief window where another thread could have released the lock before you establish the monitor.  Do you know the recommended instruction sequence?

Comment: @fuz: Oh, good point.  IDK if you can `xchg` after `monitor` without causing an instant wakeup.  Perhaps if you don't get the lock on the first try, `monitor` / load / test+jcc / `mwait`, so you have a final read-only check after the monitor is established to make sure the current value is one that warrants sleeping.  But that's just a guess on my part, I didn't double-check the docs or look for a known-good example, like if Linux uses `mwait` in `futex` if there isn't another task to run on that core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use `mwaitx` as an optimisation, not as your sole synchronisation primitive.  For this use case, it doesn't matter if it could sporadically fail.

Say for example you want to assert a spin lock

```
        mutex   dd 0
```

by setting it to `1` if it held `0` before.  The simple way to do this is to busily wait for the lock to become zero, e.g. like this:

```
again:  mov     ebx, 1
        xchg    [mutex], ebx  ; try to claim mutex
        test    ebx, ebx      ; did we succeed?
        jnz     again         ; if not, try again
```

This loop is of course quite inefficient: if the lock is held by another thread, it spins very quickly, causing a lot of expensive RMW bus accesses.  We can reduce the load using a `pause` instruction, but what would be even better was that once we knew the lock is held, we would only try to claim it once we knew that the other thread had released the lock.

The `monitor` / `mwait` instructions provide a facility to do this: you set up an address to be monitored and then get noticed when something interesting happened.  Only then do you try to claim the lock, saving you from spinning if you know that you won't get it.  It doesn't hurt if `mwait` returns early: you'll just fail to claim the lock and then go right back to waiting for it.

```
again:  mov     ebx, 1
        xchg    [mutex], ebx  ; try to claim mutex
        test    ebx, ebx      ; did we succeed?
        jz      gotit

        lea     rax, [mutex]  ; address to monitor
        xor     ecx, ecx      ; no extensions
        xor     edx, edx      ; no hints
        monitor               ; start to monitor the mutex

        cmp     [mutex], ebx  ; did the mutex change state meanwhile? (see note)
        jne     again         ; if yes, try to claim it again

        xor     ecx, ecx      ; no extensions
        xor     eax, eax      ; no hints
        mwait                 ; wait for mutex to change
        jmp     again         ; once it changed, try to get the lock again

gotit:  ...
```

*Note: a check for a change in status is needed after setting up the monitor to catch the other thread releasing the mutex after we try to claim it, but before we have armed the monitor.*

While this is good and all, there's a new problem: if the other thread doesn't yield for a while, sophisticated mutex implementations might want to switch to a different implementation, e.g. one where the kernel takes care of the lock.  This permits waiting for the lock to become available without the thread having to actually run, freeing up resources for other users.

This is hard to achieve with `monitor` and `mwait`: the waiting period is indefinite and could be very long.  AMD's `mwaitx` and `monitorx` instructions are very similar but fix this problem: they permit you to set a timeout after which `mwaitx` returns even if the memory region did not change.  This way, you can use an algorithm like ”try to claim the lock 10 times by spinning and waiting, then escalate to a kernel-based lock” and be reasonably sure of the time frame it takes to execute.

Comment: To avoid a race condition where another thread unlocks between your `monitor` and your `mwait`, Andy Glew suggests `monitor` ahead of a loop, then inside the loop, check read-only and `mwait`.  http://blog.andy.glew.ca/2010/11/httpsemipublic.html  So the monitor is already armed before the last read-only check before sleeping.  Apparently you don't need to re-rerun `monitor`?  But in user-space you should probably re-run `monitorx` since the thread might be on a different CPU core when you wake up, if it got descheduled on a timer interrupt.

Comment: @PeterCordes I assume that context switches will invalidate monitors anyway.  I found the article a bit confusing, so I added some code that should work in any case.